# Mounting USB Drive -- Cannot delete files unless have su permissions

Tags: usb, fstab, cifs

Is there a way I can automount this USB drive so that I don't need to have root privileges to delete files?

This is what I currently have in my fstab file:

```
/dev/sdb1 /mnt/epson auto defaults,user,exec,umask=777 0 0
```

When I try to delete a file in the `/mnt/epson` folder:

```
$:/mnt/epson/EPSCAN/001$ rm EPSON004.PDF
rm: remove write-protected regular file ‘EPSON004.PDF’? y
rm: cannot remove ‘EPSON004.PDF’: Permission denied
```

If I run as sudo I can delete the file.  I would like to grant any user to delete the files on the USB drive, as it is a USB stick plugged into an Epson WorkForce 840 printer and I am sharing the scans via this mounted drive.  My backup solution is to schedule a chron job to clear out the folder periodically, however I would like to allow users to delete the files.

The same goes for any actions in the folder, and I cannot change the ownership either:

```
/mnt$ sudo chown user:user -R epson
chown: changing ownership of ‘epson/EPSCAN/001/test’: Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of ‘epson/EPSCAN/001/EPSON004.PDF’: Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of ‘epson/EPSCAN/001/EPSON005.PDF’: Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of ‘epson/EPSCAN/001/EPSON006.PDF’: Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of ‘epson/EPSCAN/001’: Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of ‘epson/EPSCAN’: Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of ‘epson’: Operation not permitted
```

EDIT:

Problem solved:

Problem solved, here is my fstab file:

```
/dev/sdb1 /mnt/epson vfat user,umask=0000,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1156286

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
/dev/sdb1 /mnt/epson auto defaults,user,exec,umask=777 0 0
```

That only means that the user is capable to mount (in fact, root will be always capable to mount, so you are not changing anything), but what you where looking for was `user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions`.

Add that to your fstab line, through I prefer something more complete:

```
/dev/sdb1 /mnt/epson auto defaults,user,exec,umask=777,rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
```

The extra is `allow_other` that allows other users than the one doing the actual mounting to access the mounted filesystem.

Comment: Tried this and did not work, still getting permission denied.  My understanding is that the `user` flag allows any user to mount, which was true.  When I removed that I had to mount as sudo, before I could simply type `mount /mnt/epson`. Without user: `mount: only root can mount /dev/sdb1 on /mnt/epson`, with user: it mounts

Comment: Thank you for the help, unfortunately still getting permission denied.  Here is my fstab file: `/dev/sdb1 /mnt/epson auto allow_other,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions 0 0`  Again I _am_ able to delete the file if doing so as `sudo`

Comment: I just redid again.  I am unmounting with `sudo umount -l /mnt/epson` and remounting with `mount /mnt/epson` or when necessary `sudo /mnt/epson` -- here is the output from `mount` from your latest, still getting denied permissions: `/dev/sdb1 on /mnt/epson type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,umask=777,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,user=spiadmin)`.   My guess is this problem is being exasperated by whatever the print is doing to the USB drive, however it seems odd I can remove files if sudoed

Comment: I just mounted a vfat usb stick, this is what it came: `rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=utf8,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2`. I don't see the difference between mine and yours. Try using this verbatim sans the `uhelper=udisks2` thingy.

Comment: Thank you for all the help, here's what fixed it: 

    `/dev/sdb1 /mnt/epson vfat user,umask=0000,iocharset=utf8 0 0`

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to edit your post :)